# How can I set my Golang project version on Github

Tags: go, dep

I create a Golang project. Use dep as dependency management. I can introduce `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` v1.4.0, but I don't know how can I set this version in my project.

I'm trying to create a feature.
`git checkout -b bate-0.0.1`

An error occurred when I modified the gopkg.toml file

```
Solving failure: No versions of github.com/sillyhatxu/go-utils met constraints:
        master: Could not introduce github.com/sillyhatxu/go-utils@master, as it is not allowed by constraint beta-0.0.1 from project aftersales-backend.
        beta-0.0.1: Could not introduce github.com/sillyhatxu/go-utils@beta-0.0.1, as it is not allowed by constraint beta-0.0.1 from project aftersales-backend.
```

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/sillyhatxu/go-utils"
  version = "beta-0.0.1"
```

Comment: Maybe try using a valid [semver](https://semver.org/).

Comment: I have been fixing this problem. Golang use git's tag function for version control.

Answer (score 3):

I have been fixing this problem. Golang uses git's tag function for version control.

```
git tag v0.0.1

git push origin --tags v0.0.1
```

#### Gopkg.toml

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/sillyhatxu/go-utils"
  version = "0.0.1"
```

Comment: sometimes I need to use `git tag -a v1.0.0` release new version